# VSC: How to run a test from anywhere within test body?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I run a test using these buttons I see on top of each test:

[image]

If test size is too big, then it takes lots of scrolling to reach these buttons.

In intellij, we can run a test from anywhere within test body.

Is something similar possible in VSC?

Comment: where are you seeing these? In what kind of file?

Comment: Its a file in go language.

Comment: don't you have a list of tests in the TEST bar/View, These buttons are CodeLens buttons and are connected to an extension command